# realizar una consulta dentro de javascript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber si se puede realizar una consulta dentro de `javascript`, estuve investigando un poco y decían que abriendo `php` pero necesito utilizar el valor de la consulta para realizar unos cálculos en `javascript`. ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

este es el script que tengo dentro de el necesito hacer la consulta

```
$(document).on("keyup","#calibre,#medio",function(){
  var nom= $(this).data("nombre")
  var id= $(this).data("id_memoria")                
  var TAG_Conductor= $(this).text();
  alert(id);
  alert(TAG_Conductor);
  alert(nom);
})
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente a qué te refieres con "consulta" y viendo el código me deja aún más dudas. Podrías explicarte mejor? Saludos!

Comment: Una consulta a un DB? Estás usando sólo javascript o también php?

Comment: pues necesito traer un valor de mi base de datos en javascript y ese valor utilizarlo para hacer un calculo en el mismo script.  ¿Me entiendes?

Comment: Lo mejor para hacer esto es Ajax, tal y como ha dicho @Vera. [Aquí hay un ejemplo (pulsa **`Run - F9`** para probar el código)](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04), que hace algo parecido a lo que quieres. Toma un `ID` desde el formulario actual y en base a él busca valores en la base de datos y rellena el formulario con esos valores. Si cambias el valor del `ID` y presionas de nuevo el botón, te busca otro dato y actualiza la información, sin refrescar la página en ningún momento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para eso necesitas usar AJAX.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='resultadoID'></td>
    <td id='resultadoTAG'></td>
    <td id='resultadoNOM'></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#calibre", function() {
    var nom = $(this).data("medio");
    var id = $(this).data("id_memoria"); 
    var TAG_Conductor = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'buscadorDatos.php',
      data: {nom: nom, TAG_conductor:TAG_conductor, id:id },

      success: function(resultado) {
       $('#elementoDestino').html(resultado.split("#")[1]);
      },
      error: function(resultado) {
       console.log("Error buscarDatos: " + resultado);
       $('#observaciones').val("");
      }
    })
```

**PHP**

```
//recuperamos los valores pasados por POST desde AJAX
$id = $_POST['id'];
$tag = $_POST['TAG_conductor'];
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
//consulta SQL
$sql="select * from int_baja_tension where calibre='".$calibre."'"; 
$dato=$db->query($sql); 
if ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) { 
  $cal_uno=$row['310-17']; 
} 
$totcal1=$cal_uno*0.65;
//cuando tengas tus valores calculados de todo simplemente hacer un echo
echo "$valoresQueNecesitesEnJsSeparadosPor#";
```

Con esto estarías llamando al fichero buscarDatos.php, y le pasarías por POST tus variables recogidas en JS (id, nom, TAG_conductor).

En ese fichero PHP recoges los valores, los procesas como necesites y simplemente les haces un "echo" para mostrarlos en ese PHP (aunque tú o el usuario en realidad no lo vais a ver "pintado" en pantalla)

Como la función JS capturará lo que tu hayas puesto en el "echo", lo que te propongo es que el archivo php genere un string del tipo "dato1#dato2#dato3"... (en tu caso sería algo como por ejemplo "luis perez#tag luis perez#id luis perez") con los datos que necesites usar luego en JS separados por un #, de modo que al capturarlos luego en el success, puedas dividirlos con la funcion split, tal como ves en el ejemplo.

Así tendrías valores devueltos desde php, que podrías usar en JS para tus cálculos.

Si el php te retorna el string "luis perez#tag luis perez#id luis perez", con la función split tendrías algo así.

```
resultado.split("#")[0] ---> luis perez
resultado.split("#")[1] ---> tag luis perez
resultado.split("#")[2] ---> id luis perez
```

Comment: la verdad es que mi experiencia en javascript es muy minima y no se si se podria hacer algo asi

$(document).on("keyup","#calibre",function(){

  var nom= $(this).data("medio")

  var id= $(this).data("id_memoria") 
   
  var TAG_Conductor= $(this).text();

  if (nom="bandeja sin tapa") {

  <?php
  $sql="select * from int_baja_tension where calibre='".$calibre."'";
  $dato=$db->query($sql);
  if ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) {
  $cal_uno=$row['310-17'];
  }
  $totcal1=$cal_uno*0.65;
  ?>
 }
})

y despues la variable totcal1 llevarla a script y y la mostraria en un td

Comment: Dentro de JS no puedes (debes) meter un <?php .... ?> 
Te modifico mi respuesta para que sea un poco más clara... dame unos minutos

Comment: dale, muchas gracias